# Browser Display Problem on Motorola Droid Phone

Tags: android

I have the mobile page displayed fine in iPhone with the meta element set.

It also work fine in HTC G1 and G2 phone without the above meta tag.

However, it is totally screwed up when displayed on the HTC Droid phone such as Motorola Droid.

Does anyone know that what parameters I should set to display it properly? I have the background image with 320X480 which is the exact size of device resolution (320X480).

Answer (score 1):

DISPLAY SIZE
3.7-in.; WVGA (480 x 854 pixels); 16:9 widescreen

to ensure that, You will get the display Size and orientation of your device.

```
final Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int Screenwidth = display.getWidth();
int Screenheight = display.getHeight();
int Screenorientation = display.getOrientation();
```